# survey page in asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have requirement to create a survey web form which should be loaded from database.

Each questions will have 10 rating items from 1-10 and the result should be saved to the database with question number.

I tried to achieve it with a web form with label control at the top and RadioButtonList for options, but only one question and answer is possible to load for display at a time. I'm new to web programming. If there is any working code sample or any idea how to achieve this, it would be helpful.

I've done the coding to put each question on page and on `button click` I am  loading the next question, but I need all the questions on a single page.

```
                public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
                {
                public static SqlConnection sqlconn;
                protected string PostBackStr;

                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlconnstr"].ToString());
                PostBackStr = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "time");
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                string eventArg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
                if (eventArg == "time")
                {
                string str = "select * from tbl_Question";
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(ds2, "Question");
                int count = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                getNextQuestion(count);
                }
                }
                }
                protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                Label1.Visible = false;
                txtName.Visible =false;
                Button1.Visible = false;
                Panel1.Visible = true;
                lblName.Text = "Name : " + txtName.Text;
                int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
                lblScore.Text = "Score : " + Convert.ToString(score);
                Session["counter"]="1";
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int i = rnd.Next(1, 10);//Here specify your starting slno of question table and ending no.
                //lblQuestion.Text = i.ToString();
                getQuestion(i);

                }
                protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                string str = "select * from tbl_Question ";
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(ds2, "Question");
                int count = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                getNextQuestion(count);

                }
                public void getQuestion(int no)
                {
                string str = "select * from tbl_Question where slNo=" + no + "";
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(ds2, "Question");
                // int count = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                DataRow dtr;
                int i = 0;
                while (i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                {
                dtr = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                Session["Answer"] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32 (dtr["Correct"].ToString())-1);
                lblQuestion.Text = "Q." + Session["counter"].ToString() + "  " + dtr["Question"].ToString();
                lblQuestion2.Text = "Q." + Session["counter"].ToString() + "  " + dtr["arQuestion"].ToString();
                LblQNNo.Text = Session["counter"].ToString();
                RblOption.ClearSelection();
                RblOption.Items.Clear();
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option1"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option2"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option3"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option4"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option5"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option6"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option7"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option8"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option9"].ToString());
                RblOption.Items.Add(dtr["Option10"].ToString());

                i++;
                }
                }
                }
                public void getNextQuestion(int cnt)
                {

                if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"].ToString()) < cnt)
                {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int i = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                lblQuestion.Text = i.ToString();
                getQuestion(i);
                //qst_no = i;
                Session["counter"] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"].ToString()) + 1);

                }
                else
                {
                Panel2.Visible = false;
                //code for displaying after completting the exam, if you want to show the result then you can code here.
                }
                }




                protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                insertAns();
                }

                private void insertAns()
                {
                SqlCommand cmd;
                sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqlconnstr"].ToString());
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbl_Ans(UserID, Question_ID, Answer) values(@ans, @ans1, @ans2)", sqlconn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans1", Session["counter"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans2", RblOption.SelectedItem.Text);
                sqlconn.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();

                if (i != 0)
                {
                lbmsg.Text = "Your Answer Submitted Succesfully";
                lbmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                lbmsg.Text = "Some Problem Occured";
                lbmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                }
                #region Connection Open
                public void ConnectionOpen()
                {
                try
                {
                if (sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { sqlconn.Open(); }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                lbmsg.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                catch (SystemException sex)
                {
                lbmsg.Text = sex.Message;
                }
                }
                #endregion
                #region Connection Close
                public void ConnectionClose()
                {
                try
                {
                if (sqlconn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) { sqlconn.Close(); }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                lbmsg.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                catch (SystemException exs)
                {
                lbmsg.Text = exs.Message;
                }
                }
                #endregion

                }
```

Comment: You can do it in a single page using ajax. I think update panel is the one you want to use.

Comment: is it possible to load data from database to ajax update panel ?

Comment: update panel is just a container. We can add ASP controls inside it. You can bind data from database to any control that supports databinding inside an update panel. The main advantage of update panel is it will update all the controls through ajax so no need to postback or use another page. We can just update the existing contols with new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i want to say that you should use question table id instead of question number to save with the answer for future use.

I dont know more about dotnet so i have not attached any code here. But i can suggest you that

1. First fetch all the questions with their respective id into an object or array or fetch from them adaptor etc.
2. Then you can use a form to show them using foreach loop. for eg.

suppose "questions" is an array containing your all fetched questions from database. then apply

```
<form action="abc" method="post">

foreach(questions as question){
         <tr>
               <td>(print your question here)</td>
               <td><input type="anything you want" name="(print here    question.id)" />
         </tr>
}

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now where you will fetch data on the form submission then you can easily access the answers with their name that is already question id. So now both have associated with each other.

welcome for any query if not clear.